# How to pass boolean variable from one component to another in React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a Navbar component in which I set the state to a variable to show or hide my sidebar. Now in another component, I want to use this variable to set a class to the container (because the expanded sidebar overlaps my content). How to do this?

Navbar.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import * as FaIcons from 'react-icons/fa';
import * as AiIcons from 'react-icons/ai';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { SidebarData } from './NavbarData';
import './Navbar.css';
import { IconContext } from 'react-icons';

function Navbar() {
  const [sidebar, setSidebar] = useState(false);
  const showSidebar = () => setSidebar(!sidebar);
  console.log(sidebar)
  return (
      <IconContext.Provider value={{ color: '#fff' }}>
        <div className='navbar'>
          <Link to='#' className='menu-bars'>
            <FaIcons.FaBars onClick={showSidebar} />
          </Link>
        </div>
        <nav className={sidebar ? 'nav-menu active ' : 'nav-menu'}>
          <ul className='nav-menu-items' onClick={showSidebar}>
            <li className='navbar-toggle'>
              <Link to='#' className='menu-bars'>
                <AiIcons.AiOutlineClose />
              </Link>
            </li>
            {SidebarData.map((item, index) => {
              return (
                <li key={index} className={item.cName}>
                  <Link to={item.path}>
                    {item.icon}
                    <span>{item.title}</span>
                  </Link>
                </li>
              );
            })}
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </IconContext.Provider>
    
  );
}
export default Navbar;
```

And there is render in another component:

```
 render() {
    <Navbar /> //I tried this but don't know what else should I do
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-6 offset-1">
            <h1 className=''>Add new product</h1> //here the condition to set a class if sidebar is set to true
              <input type-"text" className="grey-text"/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have your sidebar state in the parent component of your Sidebar, so you could pass the state to you Navbar and other component.

**Navbar.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import * as FaIcons from 'react-icons/fa';
import * as AiIcons from 'react-icons/ai';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { SidebarData } from './NavbarData';
import './Navbar.css';
import { IconContext } from 'react-icons';

function Navbar({sidebar, setSidebar}) {
  const showSidebar = () => setSidebar(!sidebar);
  console.log(sidebar)
  return (
      <IconContext.Provider value={{ color: '#fff' }}>
        <div className='navbar'>
          <Link to='#' className='menu-bars'>
            <FaIcons.FaBars onClick={showSidebar} />
          </Link>
        </div>
        <nav className={sidebar ? 'nav-menu active ' : 'nav-menu'}>
          <ul className='nav-menu-items' onClick={showSidebar}>
            <li className='navbar-toggle'>
              <Link to='#' className='menu-bars'>
                <AiIcons.AiOutlineClose />
              </Link>
            </li>
            {SidebarData.map((item, index) => {
              return (
                <li key={index} className={item.cName}>
                  <Link to={item.path}>
                    {item.icon}
                    <span>{item.title}</span>
                  </Link>
                </li>
              );
            })}
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </IconContext.Provider>
    
  );
}
export default Navbar;
```

**Other component**

```
function YourOtherComponent(){
 const [sidebar, setSidebar] = useState(false);//have your state here
 render() {
    <Navbar sidebar={sidebar} setSidebar={setSidebar}/>//pass it down to your Navbar component
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-6 offset-1">
            <h1 className={`${sidebar && "SET YOUR CLASS HERE"}`}>Add new product</h1> {//you could add a class when sidebar is true}
              <input type-"text" className="grey-text"/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
)}}
```

I hope this helps you out.

Comment: thank you, I did this but now I'm getting error `setSidebar is not a function`

Comment: did you pass `setSidebar` like this: `setSidebar` or like this `setSidebar()`

Comment: I passed `setSidebar`

Comment: In Navbar.js, here in line `const showSidebar = () => setSidebar(!sidebar);`

Comment: No idea why it wouldn't work, could you maybe share your current code from your 2 files?

Comment: I put needed code on stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jea7g5?file=src/NewProduct.js

Comment: You are not rendering the Navbar component in the right place. Here is a video that explains how you should structure your Router and where you should render your Navbar component https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Law7wfdg_ls. Hope this helps you

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure what should I do, I added render `ReactDOM.render(<BrowserRouter><Navbar/><NewProduct/></BrowserRouter>, document.getElementById('root'))` but same error is showing